# Promisify prompt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

<sup>*Originally asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/498)*</sup>

---

I am trying to promisify prompt.js.
Could anyone say what i am doing wrong?

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(prompt);
prompt.start().then(function() {
    console.log("test");
    return true;
});
prompt.get(['message'], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return onErr(err);
    }
    console.log('Write a push Message repositoryName:');
    console.log('  Message: ' + result.message);
    return result;
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("hello");
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Well, for one thing you wrote a promise library and are now asking how to use it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you promisify an object with bluebird using [`promisifyAll`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyallobject-target--object-options---object) - an `Async` suffix is added by default. So instead of calling `get` call `getAsync`:

```
prompt.start(); // start is synchronous, no need to `then` it

prompt.getAsync(["message"]).then(function(response) { // note the suffix added
    console.log("got message", response.message);
    // work with message here, can use promise aggregation/chaining and use like
    // any other promise method
});
```

Quoting the documentation:

> **The promisified method name will be the original method name suffixed with "Async"**. Any class properties of the object (which is the case for the main export of many modules) are also promisified, both static and instance methods. Class property is a property with a function value that has a non-empty .prototype object. Returns the input object.

(Emphasis mine)